# Can I relabel the person.noun for Profile object type in Facebook Open Graph?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a Story using Open Graph and the object I want to use is called Service, which is really just a Profile but I want the text in the post to say 'service' rather than 'person' (which it does now). I have tried creating a custom object but it seems overly complicated for what I need so I have 2 questions:

1. Can I create a custom type that simply inherits from Profile that can be created in the same way (using the FB.api javascript method)? I don't want to have to use self-hosted types..
2. Can I simply re-label person.noun from 'person' to 'service' somehow? I can't see a way to do that..

My code to post the story is:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
if (response.authResponse) {

    var strmessage = 'Some message';
    var profileid = 'xxxxxxxxx;
    var opts = {
        profile: profileid,
        message: strmessage,
        no_feed_story: false,
        'fb:explicitly_shared': true
};

FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/me/mynamespace:myaction', 'post', opts, function (response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
    Result("Your message has not been posted");
}
else {
    //Message has been posted
    Result("Your message has been posted");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to do the custom object if you want a custom name.  And, you're going to have to do it on the FB Developer site and go through the whole approval process and all that.  And no, there is no way to do any sort of inherence on this.

FB's Open Graph is pretty simple if you use the built in actions and objects, but as soon as you go down the road of wanting custom names for stuff, you are going to have to go all in with it.

Comment: Thanks I thought as much. In that case I'll shelve it and come back to it later!

Comment: Has anybody out there been through the process of developing a custom graph object for use in a story and the Facebook approval process? How easy / painful is it?

Comment: It's not super complicated as long as you follow their guidelines.  One thing that can be a pain is making sure that the "sentence" your OG object/action creates makes sense.  "If (User) (Action) a/an (Object) on (App Name)" sounds weird, you will get rejected.

Comment: The main reason I'm avoiding it isn't the approval process, it's the lack of a clear code samples and walk-through of how to create a custom story and objects from start to finish in a language I understand. The FB documentation isn't very beginner friendly, which is a shame as it has great potential. If there was an 'Implementing custom OpenGraph user stories in ASP.Net MVC' tutorial that would be a big help to people like me who aren't from a PHP, cURL, Restful API background.

Answer (score 0):

I finally put the time aside to implement a custom action and type. It wasn't the most intuitive process but I got there in the end and my app is now approved and doing exactly what I wanted it to do. I'm actually glad I put myself through this learning process as custom stories have great potential and I'm sure I'll find other applications for them in the future.